# How to share a generated photo from an Android app without storing a file

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I have an Android app that generates photos based on a math formula. I'd like to share these photos ideally with the ShareActionProvider.

Constraints:
- Do not create files in the file system.
- Do not require any permissions. (My app requires zero permissions, and I'd like to keep it that way.)

The Android documentation suggests to create a ContentProvider for serving the files. ContentProviders return cursors of columns and rows. How do I convert a file into a Cursor?

The Android documentation says that temporary per-URI permissions have to be generated for the other app. How can I have the ShareActionProvider tell me what permissions to generate? (There is no security concern to sharing these math images with everyone. How can I give access to everyone to my provider?)

PS: I've read dozens of posts related to this topic. Most create files or use the FileProvider (which I don't know how to use without actual files).

Update: This is the closest solution that I found. Yet, it still requires creating temp files, which I'd like to avoid: [Android Share Intent for a Bitmap - is it possible not to save it prior sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049143/android-share-intent-for-a-bitmap-is-it-possible-not-to-save-it-prior-sharing)

Comment: Check whether creating a file in your app space need any permission.