# How to retrieve a bitmap from a vector image in a XML resource

Tags: android, xml, xml-drawable, android-vectordrawable, share-intent

I am reading a vector image from a XML resource and showing it in an ImageView. It's Ok.
Now, I need to pass the image to an Intent using intent.putExtra.
Question: How can I convert the vector XML to a bitmap or get the image from the ImageView?
I tried .getDrawingCache(), .getDrawable, getImageMatrix, etc, but it does not work.

Tried this way:

```
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            imgPrevisao.getDrawingCache(),
            "Minha previsão",null);

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path)) ;
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share with"));
```

And this way:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textoPrevisao );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgPrevisao.getDrawingCache() );
    intent.setType( "image/*" );
    startActivity( intent );
```

TIA,

André Corrêa

Comment: Something like that should work. Pretty standard operation to grab a bitmap from an image view.

Comment: This  intent should be handled within your application?

Comment: greenapps, sorry, something like what? I'm new with Android developing.

Comment: j2ko, no, I'm trying to share a text from my app (that works) and an image with this text (that does not work).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html):

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context context, Bitmap bmp) {
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), , "share_title",bmp ,null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

and than:

```
public static void shareImageViewContent(ImageView view) { 
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
   Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
   sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImageUri(bitmap)) ;
   context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share with"));
}
```

A bit more complicated solution is to use [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) 
Credits: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049143/android-share-intent-for-a-bitmap-is-it-possible-not-to-save-it-prior-sharing), [link](https://gist.github.com/dafi/7527494), [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents)

Comment: Thank you j2ko, I'll try that. I don't have reputation enough to upvote your answer, sorry.

Comment: @AndréAranha np, I'm glad to help. But I guess you could mark my solution    as answer

Comment: it does not work. I'm still trying. I'll post what I've tried.

Comment: Are you sure that `getDrawingCache()` returns not `null`?Did you call `imgPrevisao.buildDrawingCache()`  to be sure that it's not null?

Your second solution is incorrect - `intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgPrevisao.getDrawingCache() );` - `EXTRA_STREAM` should contain `Uri` not a bitmap object.

Comment: yes, I tried using imgPrevisao.buildDrawingCache() before calling getDrawingCache(). I'm busy lately, will try to debug again and post a better description of the error. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was a long time ago, but if someone ends up having this same doubt, I hope it helps.  I wanted to share an image and a text, as I couldn't do it the way I'd like, I made a screenshot and shared it.

```
private void shareScreenShot() {

try {
    // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                   .toString()+"/Zodiaco";

    // create bitmap screen capture
    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    //creates the directory
    File pasta = new File(mPath);
    if (!pasta.exists()) {
        pasta.mkdir();
    }

    //creates the image
    File imageFile = new File(mPath+ "/" + getDate() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    if(!imageFile.exists()){
        imageFile.createNewFile();
    }
    int quality = 100;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);

    // creates the intent and defines its action
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    // inicia a intent
    startActivity( intent );

} catch (Throwable e) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Não foi possível compartilhar a previsão.",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}