# Android can not share image without saving it?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

OK, just found another difference between iOS and Android (strange one, I think)

According to [Android Share Intent for a Bitmap - is it possible not to save it prior sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049143/android-share-intent-for-a-bitmap-is-it-possible-not-to-save-it-prior-sharing)

**I can't share an image without saving it**

In my case, I want to share a screenshot (byte array) to other apps (Facebook, Instagram, Mail, etc), but I have to save it first, no matter in internal or external storage

It's totally doable on iOS using `UIActivityViewController` with `NSArray` as input, but I can't do it with `Intent` and `ACTION_SEND` to share a byte array

Did I miss something or it's just undoable currently?

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: You totally send byte array with Intent. Refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010386/send-bitmap-using-intent-android

Comment: You are right, I will rephrase myself