# Android Share image from Url using Coil

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bitmap, coil, share-intent

My app is using Coil to load the image from external URL, when Coil loads the image I want to add option to share this image, but I do not want to ask the user for any permissions (a bit of overkill to ask for storage permission to share image),
is there any way to get the cachePath of the loaded image so I can pass it in shareIntent or some other way to share this image without asking for permissions?

> Image(
> modifier = modifier
> .clickable { click(uri) },
> contentScale = contentScale,
> painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
> ImageRequest
> .Builder(LocalContext.current)
> .data(data = uri)
> .build()
> ),
> contentDescription = null )

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Share Intent for a Bitmap - is it possible not to save it prior sharing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049143/android-share-intent-for-a-bitmap-is-it-possible-not-to-save-it-prior-sharing)

Comment: no, I have URL not bitmap